# Where and what is `linkgit:git-var`?

Tags: git

I have just checked out the [git source](https://github.com/git/git), and inside the file `Documentation/git-commit.txt`, I see the following quote.

> The editor used to edit the commit log message will be chosen from the
>   GIT_EDITOR environment variable, the core.editor configuration
>   variable, the VISUAL environment variable, or the EDITOR environment
>   variable (in that order).  See linkgit:git-var[1](https://github.com/git/git) for details.

**Where exactly can I find `linkgit:git-var`?**

I have tried grepping for this string in the source and also running web searches and cannot seem to find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It refers to the [git-var.txt](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/git-var.txt) file, you can find it in the same folder [Documentation](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/Documentation) as `git-commit.txt`.

Here is the part about the `GIT_EDITOR` variable:

> GIT_EDITOR::
>       Text editor for use by Git commands.  The value is meant to be
>       interpreted by the shell when it is used.  Examples: `~/bin/vi`,
>       `$SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE`, `"C:\Program Files\Vim\gvim.exe"
>       --nofork`.  The order of preference is the `$GIT_EDITOR`
>       environment variable, then `core.editor` configuration, then
>       `$VISUAL`, then `$EDITOR`, and then the default chosen at compile
>       time, which is usually 'vi'. ifdef::git-default-editor[]
>       The build you are using chose '{git-default-editor}' as the default. endif::git-default-editor[]

Answer (score 0):

Note that [`git var`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var) would display its "usage" if a variable is not set.

```
usage: git var (-l | <variable>)
```

This won't be the case with Git 2.40 (Q1 2023): "[`git var UNKNOWN_VARIABLE`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d818458088af2b3d6b83619668d52c9dad41b2cd/Documentation/git-var.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var))</sup>  and "`git var VARIABLE`" with the variable given an empty value used to behave identically.
Now the latter just gives an empty output, while the former still gives an error message.

See [commit 2ad150e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ad150e35e52705a97f18bee08f34e00a6557d6f), [commit 26b8abc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26b8abc7b14754d32d994f87a45b303873565853) (26 Nov 2022) by [Sean Allred (`vermiculus`)](https://github.com/vermiculus).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d818458](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d818458088af2b3d6b83619668d52c9dad41b2cd), 14 Dec 2022)</sup>

> ### [`var`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ad150e35e52705a97f18bee08f34e00a6557d6f): allow `GIT_EDITOR` to return null
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Sean Allred</sup>

> The handling to die early when there is no `EDITOR` is valuable when used in normal code (i.e., [`editor.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2ad150e35e52705a97f18bee08f34e00a6557d6f/editor.c)).
> In `git-var`, where null/empty-string is a perfectly valid value to return, it doesn't make as much sense.
>
> Remove this handling from [`git var`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2ad150e35e52705a97f18bee08f34e00a6557d6f/Documentation/git-var.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-var))</sup> `GIT_EDITOR`` so that it does not fail so noisily when there is no defined editor.

In your case, if you have not set an editor, it can be set by script easily now with, for instance:

```
git var GIT_EDITOR | export GIT_EDITOR=vi
```